# OpenXml Is there a foolproof way to replace all mail merge fields?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

Is there a foolproof way to replace all mail merge fields?
Users insert the mail merge fields using the Insert => Quick Parts => Field => Mail Merge Field.
This will the cause either a SimpleField or FieldCode to be generated.
Is there an easy way to set the values using OpenXml regardless of what field is generated?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.nuget.org/packages/docx4j.NET/3.0.1 (which I linked to in my reply to your other post) handles both simple and complex fields.  It does this by converting each to a common form as a first step in the process.

If you wanted to, you could replicate that approach/code in C# using the OpenXML SDK.